# CSS targeting a specific version of Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

The rapid cycle of updates for Firefox is starting to create problems for us, as each major update seems to introduce variation in rendering.

Is there a reliable method (javascript, or css) to target specific major versions of Firefox?

Comment: The "correct" way is to establish a baseline support for most browsers, and then provide progressive enhancement for newer browsers that support the latest CSS features. It can become a nightmare to target specific versions of browsers, especially when both Chrome and Firefox are on rapid release cycles.

Comment: @andrewap That is what I'm trying to do - we have a baseline CSS that works well in the most common browsers. We use conditional comments to target iPad and IE, and have about 3 extra rules each. I'm just trying to fix a vertical positioning problem that has come up in FF16 - I don't want to push our menu down 20px in all other browsers just to suit an apparent rendering bug in FF16.

Comment: There are ways to query the browser version using JavaScript. For example, you could use [`jQuery.browser`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/) to figure out the version and then load a specific CSS file to fix the problem. By the way, what exactly is this rendering bug?

Comment: We have a set of position: fixed elements in our menu system - but the new FF release is causing some of the content to be obscured. I can fix it by pushing one element down 20 pixels, but that would look odd in all other browsers/versions - I haven't yet done a full root-cause of the problem, though

Comment: HorusKol, have you filed a bug on the Firefox 16 behavior?  There's a good chance that doing so, with a testcase, will lead to not only figuring out why the behavior changed but also how best to work around it if needed....

Comment: I know I should file a bug - but I'd have to find a root cause first - at the moment, I'm more interested in an immediate fix than submitting a bug report right now.